# which database storage option is better for faster processing on android..?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a hotel room booking application. So far what I have done is when the user selects the check-in date, check out date and type of room , the app checks for availability and returns the status accordingly … if the rooms are available for the selected date then a new row gets inserted in the database for the particular dates and types of rooms …

Here is the code for this

```
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$type = $_POST['pincode'];
$cin = $_POST['cin']; 
$cout = $_POST['cout'];
$sql="select * from avalability where type = '$type' and cout>='$cin' an  cin<='$cout'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$check=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if(isset($check))   
{
echo "rooms not available";
}
else
{
 echo "rooms available";
$insert="insert into login.avalability(type,cin,cout) values('$type','$cin','$cout')";
 $mysqli_query($con,$insert);
 }
  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Now my question is …. Is it better to do it this way or to store the entire date database like for two years or something  and to just change the status column and keep changing the status to 1 when room is booked and to 0 when the room is free ….   So when the user check for room availability the code just has to check the status  to see if it is 1 or 0 and will return the result accordingly

Comment: Do it as you (mostly) have it now. If you go the 2nd route you'll have to keep adding on the table.. plus it's messy. Oh - and switch to PDO.

Comment: @ethrbunny  ....  Thank You very much. Can  you also tell me how to check availability for multiple Single/Double/Single A/C Rooms .... Bcoz the code i have now lets me check only for one particular type of room

Comment: loop through your resultset and examine all the `$type` entries you get back